# Rails 5: How to add folders and files in application template script

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to add folders and add files (like my own readme.md) to newly created rails apps using application templates.

In template.rb

```
require "fileutils"
require "shellwords"

def add_folders
  mkdir views/components/buttons
  mkdir csv/
end

def add_file
  cd csv
  touch user.csv
end

def add_readme
   rm README.md
   touch README.md
   inject_into_file("README.md", "New readme..")
end

after_bundle do
  add_folder
  add_file
  add_readme
end
```

But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileUtils covers most of what you want. `mkdir_p` uses the command line `mkdir -p` command, which makes the full path if the directories don't exist.

`IO.write` (which File inherits from IO) accepts a file name, and content. No need to delete the old file and touch a new one.

Also, you'll want to make sure you use `Rails.root.join` with your file paths. It's similar to `File.join`, in that it helps you build a file path without doubling up your `/` on accident, but it also returns an absolute file path on your computer. Also, it makes your code OS agnostic because while unix systems use '/' as the folder separator, Windows computers use '\'. So, `Rails.root.join` makes all of that safer.

Here's an example of using it on a unix system:

If Rails.root is `'/some/cool/path/here'`, then `Rails.root.join('views','components', 'buttons')` would be `'/some/cool/path/here/views/components/buttons'`.

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'shellwords'

def add_folders
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(Rails.root.join('views', 'components', 'buttons'))
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(Rails.root.join('csv'))
end

def add_file
  FileUtils.touch('Rails.root.join('csv', 'user.csv'))
end

def add_readme
   File.write(Rails.root.join('README.md'), 'New readme..')
end

after_bundle do
  add_folder
  add_file
  add_readme
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I used `FileUtils.mkdir_p 'csv'` following this:  
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html

Comment: @JunDalisay Be careful with that. You could end up in a bad place if you skip the `Rails.root.join` part, because you're now assuming you know what folder you're in. Skipping that part often leads to cases of "well it works on my computer, I don't know why it isn't working on yours". It's best practice to always use `Rails.root.join` and then use file paths that are relative to the root of your Rails app (like I showed).

Comment: @JunDalisay I just updated my answer with some more `Rails.root.join` explanation.